# What does _ mean in regex in java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

What does this regular express mean? Can anyone explain the significance of `_` here.

```
String s =("[ ]*[nN][eE][wW][ ]*"+s1+"[ ][\\t]*[ =_a-zA-Z]*");
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem with `_` meaning just `_`?

Comment: Just underscore `_`, nothing special. If `s1` comes from input without going through `Pattern.quote()`, you may get injected with regex.

Comment: And you don't need those brackets at the ends of your string. That is not a string literal. didn't you get a compiler error there?

Comment: can anyone give example for the regex s above

Comment: I would recommend you to make that regex more readable, for the love of god xD

Answer (score 2):

No special meaning.  So it literally means '_' character.

You regular expression means:

- Space (' ')
- followed by 'n' or 'N'
- followed by 'e' or 'E'
- followed by 'w' or 'W'
- followed by space (' ')
- followed by contents of variable s1 (probably Pattern.quote (s1) should be used here)
- followed by space (' ')
- followed by tab character repeated zero or more times
- followed by a Latin letter or underscore ('_') or equals sign ('=') or space (' ') repeated zero or more times.

Comment: Somebody changed regular expression in your question.  It was `\t` but now it is `\\t`.  For me your original variant is fine.  Tab character has no special meaning in Java regular expressions so it does not need to be escaped.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov: I edited the question, but the ``\\`` is there all along. `\t` and `\\t` are both fine. Regex also takes `\t` (backslash t) as tab character.